# Restart=Never causes the MongoDB pod to terminate

Tags: mongodb, docker, kubernetes

I am trying to follow the instructions here: https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/mongodb

1) `helm install mongorelease --set mongodbRootPassword=secretpassword,mongodbUsername=my-user,mongodbPassword=my-password,mongodbDatabase=my-database bitnami/mongodb`

which says:

To connect to your database run the following command:

kubectl run --namespace default mongorelease-mongodb-client --rm --tty -i --restart='Never' --image docker.io/bitnami/mongodb:4.2.5-debian-10-r44 --command -- mongo admin --host mongorelease-mongodb --authenticationDatabase admin -u root -p $MONGODB_ROOT_PASSWORD

I run the command above (replacing $MONGODB_ROOT_PASSWORD with my password) and I see this error:

```
error: invalid restart policy: 'Never'
See 'kubectl run -h' for help and examples
```

I remove the single quotes around Never and see this:

```
MongoDB shell version v4.2.5
connecting to: mongodb://mongorelease-mongodb:27017/admin?authSource=admin&compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2020-04-11T10:04:52.187+0000 E  QUERY    [js] Error: Authentication failed. :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:341:17
@(connect):2:6
2020-04-11T10:04:52.189+0000 F  -        [main] exception: connect failed
2020-04-11T10:04:52.189+0000 E  -        [main] exiting with code 1
pod "mongorelease-mongodb-client" deleted
pod default/mongorelease-mongodb-client terminated (Error)
```

I then remove --restart=Never from the command and run it again.  It then works expected and I can interact with MongoDB, however I am presented with this warning:

```
kubectl run --generator=deployment/apps.v1 is DEPRECATED and will be removed in a future version. Use kubectl run --generator=run-pod/v1 or kubectl create instead.
```

What is the command I should be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--restart=Never` creates a pod. So you instead can run this command with `--generator=run-pod/v1`  to create a pod. This avoids usage of `--restart=Never` and also the deprecation warning will not be there.

```
kubectl run --rm --grace-period=1 --force=true --generator=run-pod/v1 --namespace default mongorelease-mongodb-client --tty -i --image docker.io/bitnami/mongodb:4.2.5-debian-10-r44 --command -- mongo admin --host mongorelease-mongodb --authenticationDatabase admin -u root -p $MONGODB_ROOT_PASSWORD
```

Comment: Error from server (AlreadyExists): pods "mongorelease-mongodb-client" already exists

Comment: can you delete the existing deployment that was created from your previous command. I have updated my command with --rm which will delete the pod after you exit the container. so running this command multiple times will not error out

Comment: Just tried that.  The first time I run it - it just hangs.  The second time I run it I get the error.

Comment: can you press enter when it hangs? try the updated command from answer

Comment: Just tried pressing enter a few times - no different.  It just hangs.

Comment: Are you giving it right password? I faced the same when I was giving it password which is not base64 decoded

Comment: Yeah, thanks that was it - I was giving it the my-password password (not the root password).  Still I can only run the command once - the second time I run it; it says: Error from server (AlreadyExists): object is being deleted: pods "mongorelease-mongodb-client" already exists

Comment: I think I was being impatient - the error goes after 10 seconds or so.  Thanks.

Comment: I have updated the command...with this you don't have to wait